# How to implement collection with covariance when delegating to another collection for storage?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8

I'm trying to implement a type of SortedMap with extended semantics. I'm trying to delegate to SortedMap as the storage but can't get around the variance constraints:

```
class IntervalMap[A, +B](implicit val ordering: Ordering[A])
    //extends ...
{
  var underlying = SortedMap.empty[A, List[B]]
}
```

Here is the error I get. I understand *why* I get the error (I understand variance). What I don't get is how to implement this type of delegation. And yes, the covariance on B is required.

```
error: covariant type B occurs in contravariant position in type scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[A,List[B]] of parameter of setter underlying_=
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't make underlying a `var`, but you can make it a `val`.

```
scala> import collection._
import collection._

scala> class IntervalMap[A, +B](implicit val ordering: Ordering[A]) {
     |   val underlying = SortedMap.empty[A, List[B]]
     | }
defined class IntervalMap
```

In your example, `var` defines a pair of methods:

```
class IntervalMap[A, +B](implicit val ordering: Ordering[A]) {
  def underlying_=(s: SortedMap[A, List[B]]) = // ...
  def underlying: SortedMap[A, List[B]]) = // ...
}
```

For the type parameter `B` to be appear in both an input and an output, it must be invariant.